# Angular2 component js not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a web app with [Angular2](http://www.angular.io/), I'm splitting certain parts -like the header, the body and the footer- up into separate parts, so I have the following file structure (not including node_modules etc):

```
|-Root
|--|public
|--|--|css
|--|--|--|style sheets here
|--|--|img
|--|--|--|img's here
|--|--|js
|--|--|--|extra javascript here here
|--|app
|--|--|app.component.css
|--|--|app.component.html
|--|--|app.component.ts
|--|--|app.module.ts
|--|--|footer.component.html
|--|--|footer.component.ts
|--|--|header.component.html        <-- the element with problems
|--|--|header.component.ts
|--|index.html
|--|main.ts
|--|polyfills.ts
|--|vendor.ts
```

My JavaScript and CSS are being imported inside of the vendor, which looks like this:

```
// Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';

// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...
import '../public/css/animate.css';
import '../public/css/material.min.css';
import '../public/css/styles.css';

import '../public/js/material.min.js';
```

And my `header.component.html` looks like this:

```
<header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall animated fadeInDown">
    <!-- Top row, always visible -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="waterfall-exp">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </label>
        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="waterfall-exp">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bottom row, not visible on scroll -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation animated slideInRight">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Github</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Download</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact us</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
  <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
  <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Home</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Github</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Download</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact us</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

A description of this header can be found [here](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout) (scroll down untill you see a small, grey text that says 'waterfall header').

as you can see, the bottom part of this header should slide up when scrolling down, it does this when I put the header inside of `index.html` directly, but not when I use the `header.component.html`.

I finally assemble all the objects in `app.module.ts`, which looks like this:

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }     from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent }  from './header.component';
import { FooterComponent }  from './footer.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        AppComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        HeaderComponent,
        AppComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What could cause the header to not collapse when scrolling, why does it work when put directly inside of `index.html`? and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Surely you would want to bootstrap the AppComponent by itself and declare the Header and Footer component inside of it instead?

Comment: could you explain? I'm quite new to Angular @Katana24

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect your `app.module` to look something like this:

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }     from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent }  from './header.component';
import { FooterComponent }  from './footer.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
       AppComponent
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: changing the bootstrap to that disables the header and footer from loading, what would I need to add to the footer component and the header component to load them in this way?

Comment: @Grey can you create a plunkr for this?

Comment: @Grey I had a look at the github repo you posted - which you've now taken down, and the error is to do with the actual Material components you are using and has nothing to do with Angular. I suggest you have another look at how they are using them and go to their getting started page too

Comment: yes I have taken the link down, at home I included the files with NPM, but that also doesn't work

Comment: @Grey I'll have another look later when I get home if you haven't fixed it by then though I'd suggest keep on trying!

Comment: I am still trying, it's quite a fun problem to work on, even though the sollution will probably be way too simple and I'm (and maybe you are aswell?)over-complicating things :P